# Code completion list does not show after typing

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

**Preamble:**

Until today I was annoyed that there was no code suggestion for `<see langword="null"/>` in comments. When I was typing `<se`, only `<see cref=""/>` was suggested. Today, in some GitHub issues, I found out that you could write `null` and press `ctrl+space` to automatically get `<see langword="null"/>`. Great. However this was not working for me. Eventually I found out that the culprit was ReSharper. However, it worked when I changed the general IntelliSense setting in ReSharper like this:

[image]

**The Problem:**

Okay, so now the aforementioned trick is working, `null` will convert to `<see langword="null"/>` when pressing `ctrl+space`. However, automatic code suggestions stopped working altogether! When I am typing, nothing is shown, no popup, no inline code, nothing. I have to explicitly press `ctrl+space` to get the list of code suggestions. I have the following Visual Studio IntelliSense settings:

[image]

As you can see, the completion list should show, but it's not. What am I missing?

I am using Visual Studio 17.6.0 Preview 2.0 and ReSharper 2022.3.3.

Comment: Hi, what is the version of ReSharp you were used, and what about the VS version. I tried to install ReSharp on my side, but I didn't find intellisense section. Also no "Search and Navigation".

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I added the info to my question.

Comment: Does it work without ReSharper or in a non-preview version of VS?

Comment: @PiersMyers It works without ReSharper.